# Seaborn boxplot and lineplot not showing properly

Tags: python, seaborn, overlay, boxplot

I'm trying to overlay a seaborn lineplot over a seaborn boxplot
The result is someway "shocking" :)
It seems like the two graphs are put in the same figure but separate
The box plot is compressed on the left side, the line plot is compressed on the right side

Notice that if I run the two graph separatly they work fine
I cannot fugure out how to make it work
Thank you in advance for any help

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

mydata = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':[2012, 2012, 2012, 2012, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020],
    'v':[383.00, 519.00, 366.00, 436.00, 1348.00, 211.00, 139.00, 614.00, 365.00, 365.00, 383.00, 602.00, 994.00, 719.00, 589.00, 365.00, 990.00, 1142.00, 262.00, 1263.00, 507.00, 222.00, 363.00, 274.00, 195.00, 730.00, 730.00, 592.00, 479.00, 607.00, 292.00, 657.00, 453.00, 691.00, 673.00, 705]
})

means =mydata.groupby('a').v.mean().reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
sns.boxplot(data=mydata, x='a', y='v', ax=ax, showfliers=False)
sns.lineplot(data=means, x='a', y='v', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `sns.pointplot(data=means, x='a', y='v', ax=ax)` Pointplot is the equivalent to lineplot for categorical variables. Please read here more about relational and categorical plotting: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surprisingly, I did not find a duplicate for this question with a good answer, so I elevate my comment to one. Arise, Sir Comment:

Instead of `lineplot`, you should use [`pointplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html)

```
...
sns.boxplot(data=mydata, x='a', y='v', ax=ax, showfliers=False)
sns.pointplot(data=means, x='a', y='v', ax=ax) 
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

Pointplot is the equivalent to [`lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) for categorical variables that are used for [`boxplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html). Please read [here more about relational and categorical plotting](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html).

The question came up why there is no problem with `lineplot` for the following data:

```
mydata = pd.DataFrame({'a':["m1", "m1", "m1", "m2", "m2", "m2", "m2", "m3", "m3", "m3", "m3", "m4", "m4", "m4", "m4"],     'v':[11.37, 11.31, 10.93, 9.43, 9.62, 6.61, 9.31, 11.27, 8.47, 11.86, 8.77, 8.8, 9.58, 12.26, 10] })  
means =mydata.groupby('a').v.mean().reset_index()  
print(means)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8)) 
sns.boxplot(data=mydata, x='a', y='v', ax=ax, showfliers=False) 
sns.lineplot(data=means, x='a', y='v', ax=ax) 
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

The difference is that this example does not have any ambiguity for `lineplot`. Seaborn `lineplot` can use both - categorical and numerical data. Seemingly, the code tries first to plot it as numerical data, and if this is not possible uses them as categorical variables (I don't know the source code). This is probably a good software decision by seaborn because the other case (not accepting categorical data) would cause way more problems than the rare case that people try to plot both categorical and numerical data into the same figure. A warning by seaborn would be a good thing, though.

Comment: Thank you Mr. T
it works
however it is pretty funny how lineplot behaves

Comment: `mydata = pd.DataFrame({
    'a':["m1", "m1", "m1", "m2", "m2", "m2", "m2", "m3", "m3", "m3", "m3", "m4", "m4", "m4", "m4"],
    'v':[11.37, 11.31, 10.93, 9.43, 9.62, 6.61, 9.31, 11.27, 8.47, 11.86, 8.77, 8.8, 9.58, 12.26, 10]
})

means =mydata.groupby('a').v.mean().reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
sns.boxplot(data=mydata, x='a', y='v', ax=ax, showfliers=False)
sns.lineplot(data=means, x='a', y='v', ax=ax)
plt.show()`

Comment: the code I posted in last comment works fine with line plot
That's why I find lineplot behaves strange.
But sure I did not understand something

Comment: Please see the update. Maybe somebody else has more insights into the inner workings of seaborn and has a better explanation for this.